# CodeIgniter database to view help

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter and I'm trying to develop a simple website with a couple of pages. Under my "Work" view I have it looping through the database I've set up:

```
<div id="content">
<?php foreach ($records as $row){?>
  <div class="item">
   <p class="num"><?php echo $row->id;?></p>
    <h2><?php echo $row->title;?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $row->type;?></p>   
    <p><?php echo $row->brief;?></p>
  </div>
```

Right now everything works fine and the view populates the information into the view, but I want every 5th entry to have an additional class of "nomargin" added to the div. For example:

```
<div class="item">
```

1

### Title

Type

Desc

```
    <div class="item">
     <p class="num">1</p>
     <h2>Title</h2>
     <p>Type</p>        
     <p>Desc</p>
    </div>
<div class="item">
     <p class="num">1</p>
     <h2>Title</h2>
     <p>Type</p>        
     <p>Desc</p>
    </div>
<div class="item">
     <p class="num">1</p>
     <h2>Title</h2>
     <p>Type</p>        
     <p>Desc</p>
    </div>
<div class="item nomargin">
     <p class="num">1</p>
     <h2>Title</h2>
     <p>Type</p>        
     <p>Desc</p>
    </div>
```

It's prolly a simple if statement but I dont know enough about php/codeigniter to actually do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should to it

```
<div id="content">
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($records as $row){?>
  <div class="item <?php echo ($i % 5) ? '' : 'nomargin';?>">
   <p class="num"><?php echo $row->id;?></p>
    <h2><?php echo $row->title;?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $row->type;?></p>   
    <p><?php echo $row->brief;?></p>
   <?php $i++ ?>
  </div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot, this method worked well, but I set $i = 1 and also change it to: <?php echo ($i % 5) ? '' : ' nomargin';?>">

Now it works perfectly! Thanks